# How to Dir Remote Server

Tags: windows, batch-file

this is the code I have:

```
@echo off
set /p s= Rentrez l'adresse IP ou le nom du Serveur :
set /p f= Rentrez le nome du fichier :

net use \\%s%  /user:User Password
DIR /o-d \\%%s\C$\Program Files\SomeFolder | findstr /m %f%
pause
```

I want to `Dir` the folder and find the string that the user inputs.
Everything works fine until the `netuse` but after I get "network path not found".

Should I create a loop for that or something? Sorry, I'm a total noob. It's a `.bat` file.

Comment: Either the path you're entering for `%s%` is not available or is not valid. Add an `ECHO` statement in front of that line to see what is actually running.

Comment: `net use` needs a drive letter to map to. You can use `pushd \\%s%` instead.

Comment: `NET USE` can definitely be used to connect to a resource without mapping to a drive letter.

Answer (score 1):

For one thing you have a typo in the `dir` command. Plus, you need to put the path between double quotes, since it contains a space. Change

```
DIR /o-d \\%%s\C$\Program Files\SomeFolder | findstr /m %f%
```

into

```
DIR /o-d "\\%s%\C$\Program Files\SomeFolder" | findstr /m %f%
```

Also, double-check that the path `C:\Program Files\SomeFolder` actually exists on the remote host.